# Finding where a date falls in a series of date ranges excel

Tags: excel, date

In excel I have a series of available time frames for a specific task.

```
Task Date   02/05/2018
From 1      03/05/2018
To 1        07/05/2018
From 2      15/05/2018
To 2        16/05/2018
From 3      18/05/2018
To 3        21/05/2018
...         .....
```

I need to find where a specific date falls between the available time frames.
Ex: the date 2/5/2018 falls before the first period, the equation should return 1.
The dates 3/5 to and including 7/5 should return 2.
The dates after 7/5 and before 15/5 should return 3.

What I have tried:
I tried placing the value adjacent to the timeframes ranges and get its index in the sorted range. IE: `=RANK.AVG(B1,B1:B7,1)`.
But I have to find a way to convert the results to the needed format. I'm getting 1.5 and 2.5 on the first timeframe boundaries and on the other timeframe boundaries.

Is there a neat way to achieve this (other than using RANK)?
Or how can I make the values 1.5 and 2.5 converge to 2 and 3.5 and 4.5 converge to 4?

Also, I'd like to avoid VBA functions as this file would have to be sent to different people and it should work without enabling macros. (I can get a macro exception for my files but I'd rather avoid the hassle)

Answer (score 0):

> how can I make the values 1.5 and 2.5 converge to 2 and 3.5 and 4.5 converge to 4?

```
=ROUND(A1,0)-ISEVEN(A1)
```

Comment: Your answer gives 1 for an input of 2